# unable to let typescript infer the 2nd generic argument

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

The problem is best described in [**this playground**](https://tsplay.dev/wgDpbN):

```js
function infer1<T>(arg: T) {
  return arg;
}

infer1(123); // good: 123 = number ==> T number

function infer2<S, T>(arg: T) {
  return arg;
}
infer2<string>(123); // bad: Expected 2 type arguments, but got 1.(2558)
```

Why isn't `T` inferred when calling `infer2` and how can this be fixed?

Comment: Partial type inference is not supported yet. If you pass one type argument, you have to pass all of them. That's just how it is. To solve it, you can either *not* pass any type arguments, explicitly pass `T` as well, or use currying as [this](https://tsplay.dev/WYLoEm) playground shows.

Comment: Looks more like an answer than a comment. Thank you!!

Comment: Can the downvoter please elaborate?

Comment: This question was closed as duplicate. I will leave it here as both question and answer (in comments) are much easier to understand.